# The job queue and the ready queue

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, scheduler

What is the difference between the job queue and the ready queue and are they mutually exclusive?

The ready queue contains all the process stored in main memory, awaiting execution or simply all the processes that are ready to execute - which can be in the job queue?

When a new process is created which queue does it go to first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *ready queue* is a queue of all processes that are waiting to be scheduled on a core/CPU.  The process's code or data pages do not necessarily need to be in main memory.  If the OS uses [demand paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging), new processes are placed in the *ready queue* even though no pages are allocated to the process.  Non-demand paged systems will preallocate pages to a process before it goes in the *ready queue*.

According to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/which-queue-does-the-long-term-scheduler-maintain) the *job queue* is the list of processes that reside on mass storage and await main memory allocation.

So in a non-demand paged system the *job queue* and *ready queue* are mutually exclusive, and a new process goes in the *job queue*.

Answer (score 1):

Job queue contains the set of all processes in the system
and ready queue contains the set of all processes residing in main memory and awaiting execution.

Job queue consists of all the processes where ready queue contains processes which are waiting for execution is the major difference.
They are mutually exclusive as a process has to move from job queue to ready queue for execution.

When a new process is created it stays in the job queue and if is ready for execution it then moves to ready queue.